# Pymeshfix/Pyvista unexpected cleaning result

Tags: python, mesh, stl-format, pyvista

I try to repair the following mesh (a dental bridge):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Within the mesh are some holes and also intersecting triangles. I use the function ***tin.small_boundaries()*** and if i detect intersecting triangles also ***tin.clean(max_iters=10, inner_loops=3)***. Unfortunately, the dental bridge is split, leaving only one tooth in the end:

[image: 3]

Do you maybe have some ideas how i can fix this issue? You can find the used source code and the *.stl file below:
[ScriptAndModel.zip](https://github.com/pyvista/pymeshfix/files/9207852/ScriptAndModel.zip)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymeshfix



def plotMesh(tin):
    
    # return vertices and faces
    vertices, faces = tin.return_arrays()
    
    # Create object from vertex and face arrays
    meshfix = pymeshfix.MeshFix(vertices, faces)

    # Plot input
    meshfix.plot()





# Create TMesh object
tin = pymeshfix.PyTMesh()

# load stl file
tin.load_file("bridge08.stl")

# visualize input Mesh
plotMesh(tin)



###############################################################################
# CLEANING ROUTINE

# Attempt to join nearby components
# tin.join_closest_components()

# Fill holes
tin.fill_small_boundaries()
print('There are {:d} boundaries'.format(tin.boundaries()))

# check for intersecting triangles
faces = [tin.select_intersecting_triangles()]

# if intersecting triangles are detected within the mesh
if faces:
    # Clean (removes self intersections)
    tin.clean(max_iters=10, inner_loops=3)
###############################################################################



# visualize output Mesh
plotMesh(tin)
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions. [stl] is absolutely unrelated to your question.